# Two color in one Heading

Tags: customization, css

Some heading tags are coming from the template or user defined and html is look like:

```
<h1 class="myheading">Chauffeur Driven Cars in London</h1>
<h2 class="myheading">Chauffeur Driven Cars in London</h2>
```

User want to display it like this:

[image: Chauffeur Driven Cars in London]

A quick solution might be

```
<h1 class="myheading"><span class="red">C</span>hauffeur Driven Cars in London</h1>
```

But I cant apply it, as user may add any text of his choice

Is it possible to apply some **CSS** solution for this issue ?

Comment: this is off topic as it's CSS not specific to WordPress... anyway: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can do the css as:

```
h1::first-letter { 
    // your style
}
```